# Erro ao iniciar um novo projeto Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Instalei o Visual Studio 2017 a pouco tempo e funciona tudo normal. Desde ontem eu tento criar um novo projeto Xamarin e recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'Xamarin.VisualStudio.TemplateWizards, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxx'. For more information on this problem and how to enable this template, please see documentation on Customizing Projct Templates.

Até agora a única solução que achei na internet, dizia pra desinstalar o `Nuget` e reinstalar o mesmo, mas no meu VS nem aparece o `Nuget` pra desisntalar => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656261/error-this-template-attempted-to-load-component-assembly-microsoft-visualstudi

Comment: Já tentou reparar a instalação do VS? Já tive problemas parecidos e uma reparação na instalação me ajudou.

Answer (score 1):

Vá em ferramentas > Extensões e Atualizações > clique em Xamarin for visual studio, se estiver desabilitado, clique em habilitar.